# How to retreive till the last page of the table?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

In the code below I don't know where is the last page, the code below works till PAGE 25 which I mentioned manually! sometimes we have 60 or 70 pages! How can I change the code and get the table till the last page??

```
   from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd
import time
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\Webdriver\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www150.statcan.gc.ca/n1/pub/71-607-x/2021004/imp-eng.htm?r1=(1)&r2=0&r3=0&r4=12&r5=0&r7=0&r8=2022-01-01&r9=2022-01-01')
time.sleep(2)

Canada_Result=[]
for J in range (25):
    commodities = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//*[@id="report_table"]/tbody/tr["i"]/td[2]/a')
    Countries = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//*[@id="report_table"]/tbody/tr["i"]/td[4]')
    quantities = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//*[@id="report_table"]/tbody/tr["i"]/td[7]')
    weights = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//*[@id="report_table"]/tbody/tr["i"]/td[8]/abbr')

    
    for i in range(25):
        temporary_data= {'Commodity': commodities[i].text,'Country': Countries[i].text,'quantity': quantities[i].text, 'weight': weights[i].text }
        Canada_Result.append(temporary_data)
    df_data = pd.DataFrame(Canada_Result)
    df_data
    df_data.to_excel('Canada_scrapping_result.xlsx', index=False)
    # click on the Next button    
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="report_results_next"]').click()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the variable `pages` to find how many buttons there were and then work out how many pages there are by getting the text from the last non "*Next*" button on the page. This is great for dealing with multi-page selections but I have also implemented a solution in case the selection only has one page e.g. less than 25 rows retrieved.

I added an `if` statement near the start for the categories that have less rows than 25 for example this one https://www150.statcan.gc.ca/n1/pub/71-607-x/2021004/imp-eng.htm?r1=(1)&r2=9&r3=1&r4=02&r5=0&r7=0&r8=2022-01-01&r9=2022-04-01 which only has 19 rows retrieved.

The variable `period_entries` is just used to see how many row entries there are on each page. I implemented this mainly due to the last page having only 22 entries instead of 25 which broke the program initially when it got to the end.

The last `if` statement is there to ensure the program still scrapes the very last page but does not try to click the next button since it is not available.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www150.statcan.gc.ca/n1/pub/71-607-x/2021004/imp-eng.htm?r1=(1)&r2=0&r3=0&r4=12&r5=0&r7=0&r8=2022-01-01&r9=2022-01-01')
time.sleep(2)

Canada_Result=[]
pages = len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[@class="paginate_button" or @class="paginate_button current" and @title]'))
pages = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@onclick and @class="paginate_button" or @class="paginate_button current" and @title][%d]' % (pages)).text.strip("Page\n")

if pages == '':
    pages = 1

for J in range (int(pages)):
    commodities = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//*[@id="report_table"]/tbody/tr["i"]/td[2]/a')
    Countries = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//*[@id="report_table"]/tbody/tr["i"]/td[4]')
    quantities = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//*[@id="report_table"]/tbody/tr["i"]/td[7]')
    weights = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//*[@id="report_table"]/tbody/tr["i"]/td[8]/abbr')

    period_entries = len(commodities)
    
    for i in range(period_entries):
        temporary_data= {'Commodity': commodities[i].text,'Country': Countries[i].text,'quantity': quantities[i].text, 'weight': weights[i].text }
        Canada_Result.append(temporary_data)
    df_data = pd.DataFrame(Canada_Result)
    df_data
    df_data.to_excel('Canada_scrapping_result.xlsx', index=False)

    if J == int(pages) - 1:
        print("Done")
        break
    # click on the Next button
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="report_results_next"]').click()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: @ Akdeniz , Thank you so much for your explanation and working on my projects, very interesting comments and find the solution :)